# Galaxy S GT19000 shortcut bar

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

Galaxy s GT19000 I had a bar near the top on the home screen with shorcuts to wifi, synch, gps, bluetooth and brightness. They suddenly disappeared. How can I get them back?

Answer (score 2):

I think the method to restore it depends on the version of Android you're using but try holding down on an empty section of the home screen till a menu pops up and select `Widgets` and then you want the one that (on my phone) is called `Power Control`. Just hold your finger on it and drag it where you want it on the screen.

If `Widgets` isn't in the menu that pops up when you hold down on the screen then go to the main app drawer (where all of your apps are listed) and at the top select the `Widgets` tab and scroll along to `Power Control` before dragging and dropping it where you want.

Comment: No it not version dependend. I am having it both on Gingerbread and Jelly. Probably it was removed from the home screen

Comment: Sorry I meant how to add it back is version dependent, not whether or not it's there. I'll update my answer to clarify.

Comment: Cool, thats better :)